# Showing error while using mount in Ubuntu 18.04/Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ubuntu, mount

Commands want to execute ( or update_image.bash file) :

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo losetup -f /dev/loop0 floppy.img
sudo mount -t  /dev/loop0 /mnt
sudo cp -T src/kernel /mnt/kernel
sudo umount /dev/loop0
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

Error message:

```
 mount: /mnt: can't find in /etc/fstab.
 umount: /dev/loop0: not mounted.
```

actually, I am trying to build a tiny operating system. sorry if I sound noob. I am a very beginner in OS development and  I don't know much about Linux loopback devices.

[about tutorials](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/1.-Environment%20setup.html)

Extra info:

```
manish@godsmack:~/workspace/OS$ ls -l *
-rw-r--r-- 1 manish manish     247 Aug 21  2007 bochsrc.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 manish manish 1474560 Aug 21  2007 floppy.img
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manish manish     194 Dec 28 23:34 run_bochs.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manish manish     169 Jan  1 17:57 update_image.sh

docs:
total 0

src:
total 60
-rw-r--r-- 1 manish manish   800 Jan  1 14:48 boot.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 manish manish  2058 Dec 28 23:48 boot.s
-rw-rw-r-- 1 manish manish  1278 Dec 29 15:48 common.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 manish manish   553 Dec 29 15:49 common.h
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manish manish 13600 Jan  1 14:48 kernel
-rw-r--r-- 1 manish manish   602 Dec 28 23:33 link.ld
-rw-r--r-- 1 manish manish   397 Dec 29 22:08 main.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 manish manish  1188 Jan  1 14:48 main.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 manish manish   288 Dec 29 22:06 Makefile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 manish manish  4113 Dec 29 15:50 monitor.c
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 manish manish   409 Dec 29 15:50 monitor.h
```

Comment: I recommend the `-T` option of `cp` (and `mv`) it will reduce errors. (also the `-t` option).

Comment: I used -T and -t now I am getting a new error: `mount: /mnt: can't find in /etc/fstab.`
`umount: /dev/loop0: not mounted.`

Comment: edit question to show commands (including ones that give information) and error messages in correct order. Repeat all commands and paste in the result (No not do it from memory).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `/dev/loop0` is not writable. Something in an earlier step.

Comment: actually these are my steps: `sudo losetup -f /dev/loop0 floppy.img`

Comment: Add amendments to question: and show output of `ls -l floppy.img`.

Comment: manish@godsmack:~/workspace/OS$ ls -l floppy.img
`-rw-r--r-- 1 manish manish 1474560 Aug 21  2007 floppy.img`

Comment: **Add amendments to question**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `-t` option in `sudo mount -t  /dev/loop0 /mnt` -- you used `-t` and didn't specify filesystem for it so now `mount` thinks `/dev/loop0` is type and tries to find line for `/mnt` in `/etc/fstab` because it doesn't know what device should be mounted to `/mnt`.

Change the line either to `sudo mount -t <type> /dev/loop0 /mnt` (replace `<type>` with `ext4` for example) or to `sudo mount /dev/loop0 /mnt` (without the `-t` option `mount` will detect the type).

Comment: I removed -t from mount command now it is showing this error `mount: /mnt: WARNING: device write-protected, mounted read-only.
`